# IconButton missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this reusable hook component for input, which renders just fine for the TextField, but the IconButton isn't appearing.

```
const InputHookComponent = (props) =>{
  const [val, setval]=useState("");
  const cmp = <TextField
    type={props.a} 
    placeholder={props.b} 
    onChange={ 
      e => setval(e.target.value)
    } 
    value={val}
    endAdornment={
      <InputAdornment position="end">
        <IconButton 
          aria-label="Toggle visiblity" 
          onClick={ ()=>{
            // function here
          }}
          ><VisibilityOff/>
        </IconButton>
      </InputAdornment>
    }
    />
  return [val, cmp]
}
```

Component is using `@material-ui`. Been scratching my head finding out what is wrong, but I can't find out what is going wrong here.

[image: Render result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the `endAdornment` as `InputProps`, like:

```
<TextField
type={props.a} 
placeholder={props.b} 
onChange={ 
  e => setval(e.target.value)
} 
value={val}
InputProps={{
  endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">
    <IconButton 
      aria-label="Toggle visiblity" 
      onClick={ ()=>{
        // function here
      }}
      ><VisibilityOff/>
    </IconButton>
  </InputAdornment>
}}
/>
```